# What is the difference between the adjective "money-minded" and "money-driven"?

Tags: difference, adjectives

What is the difference between the adjective *money-minded* and *money-driven*? For example:

> Our boss works really hard. He is **money-driven**.
>
> Our boss works really hard. He is **money-minded**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of these two choices (-minded or -driven) to choose depends on the manner of thinking of the doer, as in this case, about money.

> Minded: having a mind especially of a specified kind or concerned with a specified thing —usually used in combination, such as narrow-minded or health-minded
>
> Driven: propelled or motivated by something —used in combination, such as results-driven or a character-driven drama

Put simply for this example, use of -minded means the doer is inclined toward concerns of money and use of -driven means the doer is obsessed with money.